# How to read file submitted through file field in block configure form

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I have created a block through custom module and added file field in block configuration form using below code.

```
function mymodule_block_configure($delta){
if($delta=='mymodule'){
    $form = array();
    $form['mymodule_file']=array(
        '#type'=>'file',
        '#title'=>'Upload text file',
        '#name'=>'files[sample]',

    );      
    return $form;
      }
 }
```

When I try to check this field in hook_block_save, the form element is empty even when the form is submitted after browsing the file.

```
 function mumodule_block_save($delta,$edit=array()){
    if($delta=='mymodule_block'){
    dpm($edit); 
    }
     }
```

`$edit['mymodule_file']` is empty after the form is submitted.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the #type 'managed_file' instead of just file: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file.

That will then automatically save the file and create a row in {file_managed}, You just need to set it as permament, as explained in the link above and then save the fid, for example with variable_set().

You can also set the #default_value for the fid, and it will display the field again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do not want to save the file. I just need to set some variables depending on file content. How can I do that? Is it possible to read the file from temporary path? Also, how can I restrict the file type to text?  My be my question title is misleading. Going to edit it now.

Comment: Ah, have a look at http://blog.ryantan.net/2011/04/drupal-7-handling-file-uploads/ then.

Comment: thanks for that. i will give it a try. But still I am not sure if it is possible to read the uploaded file without saving it.

Comment: Have a look at the linked file_save_upload() function, there you can see where it gets the files from ($_FILES).